# DataTables YADCF - do not search on arrow key presses

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am looking at this YADCF example:

http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html

1. Position cursor inside "Browser" column filter field
2. Press LEFT ARROW key

In Firebug you will notice an outgoing request to pull the data.

**Question**.

How can I prevent submission of search context if arrow keys are pressed?

Looking at the YADCF source I could not find an appropriate spot. **function textKeyUP** is triggered by inline JS events and does not know anything about Javascript *Event* object.

Thanks!

Comment: Filed an NFR: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the [0.8.9.beta.33](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/9ea72417dc805efa4ca667335c68c98839462f3f/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) in this version the text and auto complete filtes will ignore the arrow keys, if someone want more key to be igore he can send a PR with modified `keyCodes`